# Invoke a function, array, object or JSONobject in the DOM/pug file?

Tags: javascript, pug

I guess this is more a general question regarding the best pattern for this.

The use-case I have for this is that I have a pug file, in which I'd like to iterate through and for each instance use a mixin. Example for an array:

**myScript.js**

```
const myFunction() {
  return ['first', 'second', 'third'];
}
```

**page.pug**

```
script(type="text/javascript" src="./myScript.js")

block content
  each val, index in customArrayFromFunction
    +myMixin(val)

// somehow the returned value from myFunction() in myScript,
// should be usable as customArrayFromFunction
```

Would have you attach it to the DOM window object? ([Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324501/attach-function-to-domwindow-object))([Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29687814/2489480)) It kinda feels like instead of polluting the global scope, you're polluting the window object.

- Update:
  Pug is compiled using gulp.

Comment: Todd Motto wrote a [nice article](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) regarding the module pattern, and exposing a public method. Will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you're using pug, but [the pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) shows that a compiled template is returned as a JavaScript function. From there, you can call the compiled function, passing in a data object with the value you're trying to access.

Comment: Good point. I'm using gulp to build the Pug templates. I'll edit the Q